# RMarkdown suppress automatic figure numbering to html

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to suppress automatic figure numbering made by rmarkdown? The first plot rendered by R is the second figure, it added a `Figure 1:` prefix which is not what I need. I see a solution for PDF output but not html output.

[image]

Best,

Shixiang

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know what you are looking for without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But maybe you are looking for `bookdown::html_document2` output.

Try the following:

````
---
title: "Example Document"
author: "Your name here"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2
---


```{r cars, fig.cap = "plot"}   # Figure with caption
plot(cars)
```


```{r cars3, fig.cap = ""} # Figure without caption
plot(cars)
```
````

This is the output of the above:

[image]

Comment: I did not set output format, this figure comes from https://shixiangwang.github.io/home/en/post/ucscxenatools-201908/ , the source rmarkdown is https://github.com/ShixiangWang/home/blob/master/content/en/post/2019-08-20-UCSCXenaTools-notes-to-rOpenSci.Rmd